# Cycles - How can I render only pre-baked textures, and not calculate shadows?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I have an animation made in Cycles that takes place in a scene lit up by a lot of lamps, as well as a strong world background. As it would take some years to render (I made the math) I thought that baking textures would be the solution.

How can I then set the rendering so it will render only the baked texture, or at least not calculate the shadows? I haven't found a way to reduce the render times.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: It looks like I didn't express well my question.

I know how to bake, and I've already got all my textures. I just want to know how to set up the render so it wont calculate all the shadows and stuff, as that has already been made in the baking.

Comment: Baking textures in Blender - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tj-S5QAac3U its preety easy and useful! :D

Comment: The point of baking textures is that all the expensive light and shadow calculations are only done once. One long render to bake is normal, then when you use the new texture in the scene you can then render each frame in a couple of seconds. Blenderguru [explains this well](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-baking-cycles/)

Comment: Updated the question. I don't want to know how to bake, I want to know how to set up cycles to only render the textures and not calculated the shadows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to setup a material using all these baked textures and instead of a diffuse shader you have to use an emission shader.

This video show the technique very well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB09T--_ZvU

Don't be fooled by the title (cause you said you already know how to bake)

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot! However, it's quite counterintuitive, as I thought at first that a lot of emissive materials would result in noise or a lot of calculations. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from just baking and applying the image texture, remember to render by '**progressive refine**', if you are using cycles. And keep the samples in render settings to just '1'. It takes like 2 seconds to render a scene as compared to a minute or so taken while rendering the same without progressive refine.